# System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Al intentar implementar un método POST en .net

Tags: c#

Este es mi código:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostNewStudent(StudentViewModel student)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");

            using (var ctx = new SchoolEntities())
            {

                ctx.Students.Add(new Student()
                {
                    StudentId = student.Id,
                    FirstName = student.FirstName,
                    LastName = student.LastName
                });

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
}
```

Pero al compilarlo me saca esta advertencia y se me revienta. De qué forma debo organizar mi codigo para que no me saque esta excepcion no controlada?

Comment: Deberías ver el mensaje de error... Normalmente dice dónde está el error...

Comment: ¿Porqué no utilizas las herramientas de depuración que tiene Visual Studio? la mayoría de este tipo de preguntas sobre excepciones y valores null las puedes identificar mas fácil si utilizas cosas como breakpoints, monitorear los valores de variables, utilizar la ventana de salida (que muestra bastante información útil), etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, si de hecho ya lo he hecho y me dice que el StudentId esta en 0 y el student como tal esta igualado a null, si yo le quemo los valores ahí si me funciona, pero lo  necesito de tal forma que cuando yo le pase por ejemplo http://localhost:53987/api/student?Id=45&FirstName=martin&LastName=taborda, me haga el registro pero me dispara esa excepcion

Comment: Como hago para que lo que yo le pase en la barra de direcciones del navegador, me lo agregue en esas variables? porque es como si lo que yo le paso en la barra de direcciones del navegador no me lo reconociera en ese método.

Comment: Osea si yo lo dejo asi: studentId = student.Id,
                    FirstName = student.FirstName,
                    LastName = student.LastName                  Me dispara la excepcion  pero si yo lo dejo así por ejemplo   StudentId = 5,
                    FirstName = "martin",
                    LastName = "taborda"    ahi si me funciona porque los datos se los quemo directamente en el méetodo, y la idea es que me agarre desde la barra de direcciones del navaegador